# Using Event Tracking on my Website

Tags: javascript, html, events, google-analytics

I've posted some days ago a code for event tracking here, and some people helped me with the code itself.
I've pasted it on my website banner as an html code, but it's not working on my analytics. My website is already configured with the analytics, and I can't figure out why it's not tracking the information. 
This is the page with the buttom:
http://www.congressosecurityleaders.com.br/sao-paulo

Here is the code:
    
    
    
       Com tecnologia Eventbrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many, and the wrong kind of, quotation marks. This is what your code looks like:

```
onclick="”ga(‘send’," ‘event’,="" ‘inscrição="" sp’,="" ‘click’,="" ‘security="" leaders’);”=""
```

There are extra double quotes, and you have to use 'straight' single quotes (not the ‘typographical’ ones) . And I'm not sure where the equal signs come from - it looks a little like you tried to use diacritic marks that have been garbled by a wrong setting for character encoding.

Comment: After I make the right changes where should I put the code? After the href? I'm don't know much about html placement, sorry.

Comment: onclick="ga('send'," 'event',=" 'inscrição=" sp',=" 'click',=" 'security=" leaders');"="

Without the =?

Comment: Without the "=". It does not matter if the code is placed before or after the href, it just needs to be within the <angled brackets>.

Comment: Thanks! This is the code I ended up with 
onclick"ga('send'," 'event'," 'inscrição" sp'," 'click'," 'security" leaders');"

Comment: Thanks for the help!